# How to remove Notification in Settings in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, notifications, apple-push-notifications

Using Parse service, I implemented Apple Push Notification service in my app.
This is a link I referred: https://parse.com/tutorials/push-notifications

However, I changed my mind not to use it for now. And then, I deleted all of the codes, but it still remains Notifications in Settings.

[image]

Does anybody know how to delete if for all eternity?

Answer (score 0):

Turn it off for the app in the settings and then delete and reinstall the app on the the device.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried your instruction, but it still remains. Appreciate your more advices if you don't mind. Cheers